# Mongoose ODM model creation problems

Tags: node.js, express, model, mongoose, schema

I am trying to create models in mongoose using an express app.
the error i am getting is the following:

```
Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
```

My Setup is the following:

1. I have a module names Schemas which I am linking to my Express app using npm link
2. The Schemas module has an entry point index.js which has the following

   ```
   module.exports = require('./lib/index');
   ```
3. The above required index file(./lib/index.js) has:

   ```
   module.exports = {    InstituteSchema: require('./Schemas/Institute') }
   ```
4. The above Institute file(./Schemas/Institute) has the following:

   ```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var RegistrySchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   privileges: [String]
   });

   module.exports = RegistrySchema;
   ```
5. The following is an extract of my express app:

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Project');
   var http = require('http');
   var path = require('path');
   var routes = require('./routes');
   var RegistrySchema = require('Schemas').RegistrySchema;
   var RegistryModel = mongoose.model('Registry', RegistrySchema);
   ```

however when I run Express i get the following stack trace:

```
   /usr/local/bin/node app.js

   /Users/user/Documents/WebstormProjects/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:362 throw new TypeError('Undefined type at `' + path +

   TypeError: Undefined type at `paths.name`
   Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (/Users/user/Documents/WebstormProjects/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:362:11)
at Schema.path (/Users/user/Documents/WebstormProjects/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:305:29)
at Schema.add (/Users/user/Documents/WebstormProjects/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:217:12)
at Schema.add (/Users/user/Documents/WebstormProjects/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:212:14)
at new Schema (/Users/user/Documents/WebstormProjects/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:73:10)
at Mongoose.model (/Users/user/Documents/WebstormProjects/Project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:293:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/WebstormProjects/Project/app.js:12:30)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

Comment: the require is wrong - require('Schemas').InstituteSchema;

Also, the way you are requiring stuff in your /lib/index.js will later get you into problem. use __dirname and path.join instead.

Comment: can you please more specific so i can understand how things work,,,i am new to node and one particular point of confusion is "exporting" the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you have a models directory within which you have a file defined for each model. In the model file export the model itself.

In models/Registry.js -

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Registry', RegistrySchema);
```

And in your app.js, just require all the model files -

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    modelPath = __dirname + '/models';

fs.readdirSync(modelPath).forEach(function(file) {
    require(modelPath + '/' + file);
});
```

Have a look at the MEAN stack boilerplace structure - https://github.com/linnovate/mean/tree/master/app

Also have a look at this article to understand how require works - 
http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/